# Server Error '\' in Application

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

am working on my first MVC 5 application. Unfortunately I have run into an error and after searching the internet for the past 4 hours, cannot figure how to fix it. Basically I keep getting the following error.[image: error I get]

I understand what the error means. But my Profile view is supposed to be under the Manage view. Basically when a user logs in they should see a new link that says view my profile. Its location should be /Account/Profile not /Home/Profile.

Do I need to change this in the application routing or should I remove the reference I have to this view in the HomeController and instead move it to the AccountController?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `view my profile` link and it's associated controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller that generates a view doesn't restrict you to only that controller, your links can point to any controller. So in your view when you render the link to the Profile view you should specify the controller name.

In the following example I'm using the overload of ActionLink that lets me specify the controller (i.e. Account) that contains the action (i.e. Profile).

```
Html.ActionLink( "View My Profile", "Profile", "Account" )
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed to do. Overloading the ActionLink helper did the trick. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC by default checks first for the respective view in `\Views\[ControllerDirectory]\`, but after that, if it doesn't find a match, then it looks in `\Views\Shared` folder.

Having a view in the shared directory you can share views across multiple controllers. You can add your `Profile` view to the `Shared` subdirectory and you should be fine. If you still prefer to have the `Profile` view under `Account` Controller and want to reference from other controller's action then change your return statement to specify the location of the view like below.

```
public ActionResult ProfileAction()
{
    return View("../Account/Profile");
}
```